# How to show help_text on buildQuickForm elements

Tags: extension

I'm using buildQuickForm in an extension to allow editing of some custom settings.  It's working well, but when I created the custom settings there was a field called, "help_text".  I can't seem to figure out how to display the "help_text" in the form elements.

I create the settings in a page called givingstatements.setting.php and this is the code from that page

/*
 * https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.autogroup/blob/master/settings/autogroup.setting.php
 */
return array(

```
/*
 * When to show legal statement on giving statements
 */
'givingstatements_show_legal_statement' => array(
    'title' => 'Always show legal statement on giving statements',
    'group_name' => 'givingstatements_show_legal_statement',
    'group' => 'CiviCRM Preferences',
    'name' => 'givingstatements_show_legal_statement',
    'type' => 'String',
    'default' => '0',
    'add' => '4.7',
    'is_domain' => 1,
    'is_contact' => 0,
    'description' => 'Always show legal statement on giving statements.',
    'help_text' => 'If no, legal statement will only appear on statements that are 1 full year',
    'quick_form_type' => 'YesNo', // Without this it will not appear on the settings form.
    //'quick_form_type' => 'Element', // Without this it will not appear on the settings form.
    'html_type' => 'radio',
),

/*
 * Default option for combining giving statements for spouses
 */
'givingstatements_combine_spouse_default' => array(
    'title' => 'Combine giving statements for spouses by default',
    'group_name' => 'givingstatements_combine_spouse_default',
    'group' => 'CiviCRM Preferences',
    'name' => 'givingstatements_combine_spouse_default',
    'type' => 'String',
    'default' => '0',
    'add' => '4.7',
    'is_domain' => 1,
    'is_contact' => 0,
    'description' => 'Combine giving statements for spouses by default.',
    'help_text' => 'User preferences will override this option.',
    'quick_form_type' => 'YesNo', // Without this it will not appear on the settings form.
    //'quick_form_type' => 'Element', // Without this it will not appear on the settings form.
    'html_type' => 'radio',
),

/*
 * Allow individuals without civicontribute access to enter custom date ranges
 */
'givingstatements_custom_date_range_allowed' => array(
    'title' => 'Allow individuals without civicontribute access to enter custom date ranges',
    'group_name' => 'givingstatements_custom_date_range_allowed',
    'group' => 'CiviCRM Preferences',
    'name' => 'givingstatements_custom_date_range_allowed',
    'type' => 'String',
    'default' => '0',
    'add' => '4.7',
    'is_domain' => 1,
    'is_contact' => 0,
    'description' => 'Allow individuals without civicontribute access to enter custom date ranges.',
    'help_text' => 'If set to no, individuals will only be able to select full years.',
    'quick_form_type' => 'YesNo', // Without this it will not appear on the settings form.
    //'quick_form_type' => 'Element', // Without this it will not appear on the settings form.
    'html_type' => 'radio',
),
);
```

My page that creates the form is called Settings.php and the code on that page is this
[image]

My tpl page has this code

```
  {foreach from=$elementNames item=elementName}
<div class="crm-section">
  <div class="label">{$form.$elementName.label}</div>
  <div class="content">{$form.$elementName.html}</div>
  <div class="help">({$form.$elementName.help_text})</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

But $form.$elementName.help_text is empty
If I do {$form.$elementName|@debug_print_var} I get the array and it doesn't contain help_text, or the contents of help_text under a different key.  It outputs

(Array (11)
name => "givingstatements_show_legal_statement"
value => "1"
type => "group"
frozen => false
required => true
error => null
label => " Always show legal statement ..."
separator => null
html => " Array (9)
  name => "givingstatements_show_legal_statement"
  value => "1"
  type => "radio"
  frozen => false
  required => false
  error => null
  id => "CIVICRM_QFID_1_givingstatements_show_..."
  label => " " Array (9)
  name => "givingstatements_show_legal_statement"
  value => "0"
  type => "radio"
  frozen => false
  required => false
  error => null
  id => "CIVICRM_QFID_0_givingstatements_show_..."
  label => " "

If I go to the CiviCRM api page I can return the help_text there so I know it's storing it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best answer but many of the core settings tpl's have the help text directly in the tpl, e.g. `<span class="description">{ts}Here is the help text{/ts}</span>`. Unless you want your users to be able to edit the help text, that seems like a good enough solution here(?), since your tpl is your own custom file to begin with.

EDIT: An alternative:
(Haven't tested this, just as a sketch of proof of concept.)

In buildQuickForm in your loop add a line like this:

`$help_texts[$key] = $result['values'][$key]['help_text'];`

Then after the loop add a line:

`$this->assign('help_texts', $help_texts);`

Then in the tpl inside the loop:

`<div class="help">({$help_texts.$elementName})</div>`

Comment: Notice that I’m calling the code in the tpl file in a foreach loop.  I can’t statically set text in that loop.  Obviously I could do if/else statements to check if the element name is each one and then set the help text, but that’s not a great way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah, the core ones that do this don't use a loop. I guess that is an option if you're not planning to change your settings list too often. Can I also ask what is "data-something" in your buildQuickForm - if you view the source of the rendered page is there an attribute on the input element called data-something that has your help text?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that was in there.  I had been trying to test some things in the buildQuickForm code and just used that as a temporary var to see if I could get it to populate with the help_text.

Comment: That could be an alternate option too then. Set a different array with your help text in buildQuickForm, keyed on the same $key, and use `$this->assign` to assign it to the template, and then access it in your smarty loop.

Comment: I think you're on to something there! I just need to figure out how to concatenate the variable name from the $key and the string in smarty. So, I'm doing this in buildQuickForm now

foreach($this->_settings AS $key => $value){
  $result = civicrm_api3('Setting', 'getfields', [
   'name' => $key,
  ]);
  $this->assign($key.'-help_text', $result['values'][$key]['help_text']);
  //print_r($result['values'][$key]['help_text']);
 }

I've verified that the print_r is the value I want.  My only question is, how to concatenate the variable string in smarty for the tpl file?

Comment: You could do it that way, or see my edited answer. If you really want to concatenate try the {assign} smarty tag.

Comment: Excellent!  The edited answer works.  I don't think it's the best way to do it, because I'm fairly certain there's a way to add it to the $elementName array by using some of the built in functionality, but for now this gets me moving forward.  I really appreciate it.  I'm not going to mark it as answered though because I'd really like to know the "correct" way of doing it.  I think the answer is somewhere on this page, but I couldn't figure it out.  https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/quickform/